# $L \subseteq \Sigma^*$ is decidable $\iff$ $I_L$ is computable

Tags: logic, turing-machines

Let us denote $L \subseteq \Sigma^*$ a languague where $\Sigma$ is an alphabet. I want to show that

$$L \subseteq \Sigma^* \ is \ decidable \iff I_L \ is \ computable,$$ 
where $I_L$ is an indicator function.

I have those definitions:

$L$ is decidable if there exists a Turing Machine (TM) M which decides $L$, which means, that $x \in L \implies$ M accepts $x$ and $x \notin L \implies$ M rejects $x$.

Function $f$ is said to be computable, if $dom(f)=\Sigma^*$ and there exists TM which computes $f$, which means that $L(M)=dom(f)$ and $\forall x \in dom(f)$ there is a sequence of configurations $c_0,...,c_n$ such that $c_0$ is initial, $c_i$ yields $c_{i+1}$ and $c_n = [q_{acc},h,f(x){\sqcup}^{\omega}]$.

I feel like I am missing something. If $y\in \Sigma^* \setminus L$, then if $L \subseteq \Sigma^*$ is decidable, then $M$ rejects $y$, therefore $y \notin L(M)$. However $dom(f)=\Sigma^*$ so it holds that $L(M) \neq dom(f)$ and therefore $I_L$ is not computable. And i get he same problem for the implication "from right to left".
Where is the problem? Did I made mistake while writing definitions?

Edit: Sorry, I did not write all definitions. So
$L(M)=\{ x\in \Sigma^* |M \ accepts \ x \}$

$M$ accepts $x$ if there exists a sequence of configurations $c_0,...,c_n$ such that $c_0$ is initial, $c_i$ yields $c_{i+1}$ and $c_n$ is accepting configuration.

$M$ rejects $x$ if there exists a sequence of configurations $c_0,...,c_n$ such that $c_0$ is initial, $c_i$ yields $c_{i+1}$ and $c_n$ is rejecting configuration.

$q_{acc}$ is an accepting configuration

$h$ is position of the reading and writing head.

$f(x){\sqcup}^{\omega}$ means that in the first cell of TM is the value of $f(x)$ and in the rest cells there are blank symbols.

Comment: You're not helping people to help you. What is your definition of "accepts" and "rejects"? What is $L(M)$? And so on. This whole problem basically amounts to translating between definitions, so it's important to include them. And you might answer the question yourself after you fully flesh them out.

Comment: I am sorry, I added those definitions. However the problem is still the same.